# Prevent animation from displaying backwards (Animate.css - React.js)

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, animation

I am using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to give some animations to some images and buttons in my page on scroll. I have to say that my project is being developed with React.js, and Animate.css is imported as a component.

[Link to React library to animate on scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-scroll)

The thing is that I don't know how to display my animations once (when the user is scrolling down) and then stop them if the user wants to go upwards (because now are displayed again...).

As I've provided in the link, to use a component, you have to wrap whatever you want to animate:

```
<ScrollAnimation animateIn="fadeIn">
  Some Text
</ScrollAnimation>
```

This component has a number of limited properties, such as `animateIn`, where you can specify an animation from Animate.css to be displayed

Oher properties are:

```
animateOut
duration - default 1
initiallyVisible - default false
delay - default 0
```

I've tried to modify the animate.css.min that has to be linked to the project, changing values like `animation-iteration-count:infinite;`to `1`, or `animation-fill-mode:both;`to `forwards`, but I've been unsuccessful... Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to avoid displaying the animation backwards. In the same thread on GitHub, in the section of issues, there was an answer for that:

[Github answer](https://github.com/dbramwell/react-animate-on-scroll/commit/1464794c1568e38550f09ff700bb942e111b4aef)

I only had to make my own javascript document, copy and paste the new answer, and once it was done, to edit the route from my main page where I was calling the component. It changed to:

```
import ScrollAnimation from './scroll-animation';
```

Where `scroll-animation` is the name of my javascript document.

The last step was to use the new feature that was added `animateOnce`:

```
<ScrollAnimation animateIn="slideInLeft" animateOnce="true">
```

And there you go, now the animations will display only on scroll and not backwards.